# Renaming columns in pandas dataframe error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to combine datas from more csv files, selecting just particular columns and renaming their labels. I have this code:

```
import datetime as dt
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as dt
import pandas_datareader.data as web

def get_data_from_yahoo():
    start = dt.datetime(1970,1,1)
    today = dt.datetime.now()

    for ticker in tickers:
        print(ticker)
        if not os.path.exists('my_portfolio/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
            df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, today)
            df[ticker+' Returns'] = np.log(df['Adj Close'] / df['Adj Close'].shift(1))
            df.to_csv('my_portfolio/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
        else:
            print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))

tickers = ['SYNC', 'TAT', 'CRNT', 'ZX', 'NNA', 'CPLP', 'ROIA', 'WLB', 'VSTM', 'VOC', 'GFN', 'ROIA', 'SPY']          
get_data_from_yahoo()

def compile_data():
    main_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for count, ticker in enumerate(tickers):
        df = pd.read_csv('my_portfolio/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
        df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
        df.rename(columns={'Adj Close':ticker}, inplace=True)
        df.drop(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'], 1, inplace=True)

        if main_df.empty:
            main_df = df
        else:
            main_df = main_df.join(df, how='outer')

    print(main_df.tail())
    main_df.to_csv('joinedPortfolioCloseReturns.csv')

compile_data()
```

After running the program, downloading the datas and saving as csv files is working. But then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-37-dbff02b25dd0>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/Morandi/Documents/Python/Finances/myPortfolio.py', wdir='/Users/Morandi/Documents/Python/Finances')

  File "/Users/Morandi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/Morandi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/Morandi/Documents/Python/Finances/myPortfolio.py", line 51, in <module>
    compile_data()

  File "/Users/Morandi/Documents/Python/Finances/myPortfolio.py", line 46, in compile_data
    main_df = main_df.join(df, how='outer')

  File "/Users/Morandi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4555, in join
    rsuffix=rsuffix, sort=sort)

  File "/Users/Morandi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4569, in _join_compat
    suffixes=(lsuffix, rsuffix), sort=sort)

  File "/Users/Morandi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 62, in merge
    return op.get_result()

  File "/Users/Morandi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 556, in get_result
    rdata.items, rsuf)

  File "/Users/Morandi/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4699, in items_overlap_with_suffix
    to_rename)

ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['ROIA', 'ROIA Returns'], dtype='object')
```

Anybody can help?
Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: You're using `join` which joins on indices, when you have clashes in row values you must specify the suffixes, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645515/pandas-join-issue-columns-overlap-but-no-suffix-specified

Comment: ed, that's a good answer... and really should be in an answer box.

Comment: Thank you @EdChum, I specified the suffixes in this way and it started to work:

                    main_df = main_df.join(df, how='outer', lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right')