# Concatenate two dataframes by column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join

I have 2 dataframes. First dataframe contain number of year and count with 0:

```
    year  count
0    1890      0
1    1891      0
2    1892      0
3    1893      0
4    1894      0
5    1895      0
6    1896      0
7    1897      0
8    1898      0
9    1899      0
10   1900      0
11   1901      0
12   1902      0
13   1903      0
14   1904      0
15   1905      0
16   1906      0
17   1907      0
18   1908      0
19   1909      0
20   1910      0
21   1911      0
22   1912      0
23   1913      0
24   1914      0
25   1915      0
26   1916      0
27   1917      0
28   1918      0
29   1919      0
..    ...    ...
90   1980      0
91   1981      0
92   1982      0
93   1983      0
94   1984      0
95   1985      0
96   1986      0
97   1987      0
98   1988      0
99   1989      0
100  1990      0
101  1991      0
102  1992      0
103  1993      0
104  1994      0
105  1995      0
106  1996      0
107  1997      0
108  1998      0
109  1999      0
110  2000      0
111  2001      0
112  2002      0
113  2003      0
114  2004      0
115  2005      0
116  2006      0
117  2007      0
118  2008      0
119  2009      0

[120 rows x 2 columns]
```

Second dataframe have similar columns but filled with smaller number of years and filled count:

```
  year  count
0   1970      1
1   1957      7
2   1947     19
3   1987     12
4   1979      7
5   1940      1
6   1950     19
7   1972      4
8   1954     15
9   1976     15
10  2006      3
11  1963     16
12  1980      6
13  1956     13
14  1967      5
15  1893      1
16  1985      5
17  1964      6
18  1949     11
19  1945     15
20  1948     16
21  1959     16
22  1958     12
23  1929      1
24  1965     12
25  1969     15
26  1946     12
27  1961      1
28  1988      1
29  1918      1
30  1999      3
31  1986      3
32  1981      2
33  1960      2
34  1974      4
35  1953      9
36  1968     11
37  1916      2
38  1955      5
39  1978      1
40  2003      1
41  1982      4
42  1984      3
43  1966      4
44  1983      3
45  1962      3
46  1952      4
47  1992      2
48  1973      4
49  1993     10
50  1975      2
51  1900      1
52  1991      1
53  1907      1
54  1977      4
55  1908      1
56  1998      2
57  1997      3
58  1895      1
```

I want to create third dataframe df3. For each row, if year in df1 and df2 are equal, then df3["count"] = df2["count"] else df3["count"] = df1["count"].
I tried to use join to do this:

```
df_new = df2.join(df1, on='year', how='left')
df_new['count'] = df_new['count'].fillna(0)
print(df_new)
```

But got an error:

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['year'], dtype='object')
```

I found the solution to this error([Pandas join issue: columns overlap but no suffix specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645515/pandas-join-issue-columns-overlap-but-no-suffix-specified)) But after I run code with those changes:

```
df_new = df2.join(df1, on='year', how='left', lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right')
df_new['count'] = df_new['count'].fillna(0)
print(df_new)
```

But output is not what I want:

```
    count  year
0     NaN  1890
1     NaN  1891
2     NaN  1892
3     NaN  1893
4     NaN  1894
5     NaN  1895
6     NaN  1896
7     NaN  1897
8     NaN  1898
9     NaN  1899
10    NaN  1900
11    NaN  1901
12    NaN  1902
13    NaN  1903
14    NaN  1904
15    NaN  1905
16    NaN  1906
17    NaN  1907
18    NaN  1908
19    NaN  1909
20    NaN  1910
21    NaN  1911
22    NaN  1912
23    NaN  1913
24    NaN  1914
25    NaN  1915
26    NaN  1916
27    NaN  1917
28    NaN  1918
29    NaN  1919
..    ...   ...
29    1.0  1918
30    3.0  1999
31    3.0  1986
32    2.0  1981
33    2.0  1960
34    4.0  1974
35    9.0  1953
36   11.0  1968
37    2.0  1916
38    5.0  1955
39    1.0  1978
40    1.0  2003
41    4.0  1982
42    3.0  1984
43    4.0  1966
44    3.0  1983
45    3.0  1962
46    4.0  1952
47    2.0  1992
48    4.0  1973
49   10.0  1993
50    2.0  1975
51    1.0  1900
52    1.0  1991
53    1.0  1907
54    4.0  1977
55    1.0  1908
56    2.0  1998
57    3.0  1997
58    1.0  1895

[179 rows x 2 columns]
```

Desired output is:

```
     year  count
0    1890      0
1    1891      0
2    1892      0
3    1893      1
4    1894      0
5    1895      1
6    1896      0
7    1897      0
8    1898      0
9    1899      0
10   1900      1
11   1901      0
12   1902      0
13   1903      0
14   1904      0
15   1905      0
16   1906      0
17   1907      1
18   1908      1
19   1909      0
20   1910      0
21   1911      0
22   1912      0
23   1913      0
24   1914      0
25   1915      0
26   1916      2
27   1917      0
28   1918      1
29   1919      0
..    ...    ...
90   1980      6
91   1981      2
92   1982      4
93   1983      3
94   1984      3
95   1985      5
96   1986      3
97   1987     12
98   1988      1
99   1989      0
100  1990      0
101  1991      1
102  1992      2
103  1993     10
104  1994      0
105  1995      0
106  1996      0
107  1997      3
108  1998      2
109  1999      3
110  2000      0
111  2001      0
112  2002      0
113  2003      1
114  2004      0
115  2005      0
116  2006      3
117  2007      0
118  2008      0
119  2009      0

[120 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue if because you should place `year` as index. In addition, if you don't want to lose data, you should join on `outer` instead of `left`.

This is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "year" : np.random.randint(1850, 2000, size=(100,)),
    "qty" : np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(100,)),
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "year" : np.random.randint(1850, 2000, size=(100,)),
    "qty" : np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(100,)),
})

df = df.set_index("year")
df2 = df2.set_index("year")

df3 = df.join(df2["qty"], how = "outer", lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right')
df3 = df3.fillna(0)
```

At this step you have 2 columns with values from df1 or df2. In you merge rule, I don't get what you want. You said :

> - if df1["qty"] == df2["qty"] => df3["qty"] = df2["qty"]
> - if df1["qty"] != df2["qty"] => df3["qty"] = df1["qty"]

That means you want everytime `df1["qty"]` because of `df1["qty"] == df2["qty"]`. Am I right ?

Just in case. If you want a code to adjust you can use `apply` as follow :

```
def foo(x1, x2):
    if x1 == x2:
        return x2
    else:
        return x1

df3["count"] = df3.apply(lambda row: foo(row["qty_left"], row["qty_left"]), axis=1)
df3.drop(["qty_left","qty_right"], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

I hope it helps,

Nicolas

Comment: Thanks, that exactly what i want. I just delete index, convert to int column "count" and rename columns headers

Comment: you are welcome :) Thanks for accepting the answer btw