# Take three groupby dataframes and concatenate/merge - BUT one dataframe is aggregated at a higher level

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, pandas-groupby

Afternoon All,

I have three large grouped by results. Simplified df are presented below. The first df is all Client's Total RFQ's and Total RFQ Volumes whith no breakedown via Product and Currency.

```
df1 = [('Year_Month', ['2017-11', '2017-12', '2018-01', '2018-02', '2018-05', '2018-06', '2018-07', '2018-08',]),
('Client', ['RBMI', 'RBMI', 'RBMI', 'RBMI', 'QCBO', 'QCBO', 'QCBO', 'QCBO',]),
('Total_RFQ_per_Client', [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20, 30, 40,]),
('Total_RFQ_Volume_per_Client', ['1000', '2000', '3000', '4000', '10000', '20000', '30000', '40000',]),
         ]
# create pandas df
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(df1)
df1['Total_RFQ_per_Client']=df1.Total_RFQ_per_Client.astype('int64')
df1['Total_RFQ_Volume_per_Client']=df1.Total_RFQ_Volume_per_Client.astype('int64')
print(df1)
# df1.info()
print("")

  Year_Month Client  Total_RFQ_per_Client  Total_RFQ_Volume_per_Client
0    2017-11   RBMI                     1                         1000
1    2017-12   RBMI                     2                         2000
2    2018-01   RBMI                     3                         3000
3    2018-02   RBMI                     4                         4000
4    2018-05   QCBO                    10                        10000
5    2018-06   QCBO                    20                        20000
6    2018-07   QCBO                    30                        30000
7    2018-08   QCBO                    40                        40000
```

The second df is all Client's RFQ's and RFQ Volumes which were done and with Product and Currency columns added.

```
print("All Clients - Done RFQ's - Done RFQ Volume - Broken down into Product and Currency",  end='\n') 
df2 = [('Year_Month', ['2017-11', '2018-01', '2018-01', '2018-02', '2018-05', '2018-07', '2018-08',]),
('Client', ['RBMI', 'RBMI', 'RBMI', 'RBMI', 'QCBO', 'QCBO', 'QCBO',]),
('Product', ['GOVT', 'GOVT', 'CORP', 'GOVT', 'GOVT', 'GOVT', 'GOVT',]),
('currency_str', ['USD', 'USD', 'GBP', 'USD', 'USD', 'USD', 'USD',]),
('Done_RFQ', [1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 20, 20,]),
('Done_RFQ_Volume', [1000, 500, 500, 1000, 10000, 20000, 20000,]),
         ]
# create pandas df
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(df2)
df2['Done_RFQ']=df2.Done_RFQ.astype('int64')
df2['Done_RFQ_Volume']=df2.Done_RFQ_Volume.astype('int64')
print(df2)
# df2.info()
print("")

0    2017-11   RBMI    GOVT          USD         1             1000
1    2018-01   RBMI    GOVT          USD         1              500
2    2018-01   RBMI    CORP          GBP         1              500
3    2018-02   RBMI    GOVT          USD         1             1000
4    2018-05   QCBO    GOVT          USD        10            10000
5    2018-07   QCBO    GOVT          USD        20            20000
6    2018-08   QCBO    GOVT          USD        20            20000
```

The third df is all Client's RFQ's and RFQ Volumes which were NOT done and with Product and Currency columns added.

```
df3 = [('Year_Month', ['2017-12', '2018-01', '2018-02', '2018-06', '2018-07', '2018-08',]),
('Client', ['RBMI', 'RBMI', 'RBMI', 'QCBO', 'QCBO', 'QCBO',]),
('Product', ['GOVT', 'CORP', 'GOVT', 'GOVT', 'GOVT', 'CORP',]),
('currency_str', ['USD', 'GBP', 'USD', 'USD', 'USD', 'CAD',]),
('Not_Done_RFQ', [2, 1, 3, 20, 10, 20,]),
('Not_Done_RFQ_Volume', [2000, 2000, 3000, 20000, 10000, 20000,]),
         ]
# create pandas df
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(df3)
df3['Not_Done_RFQ']=df3.Not_Done_RFQ.astype('int64')
df3['Not_Done_RFQ_Volume']=df3.Not_Done_RFQ_Volume.astype('int64')
print(df3)
# df3.info()
print("")

  Year_Month Client Product currency_str  Not_Done_RFQ  Not_Done_RFQ_Volume
0    2017-12   RBMI    GOVT          USD             2                 2000
1    2018-01   RBMI    CORP          GBP             1                 2000
2    2018-02   RBMI    GOVT          USD             3                 3000
3    2018-06   QCBO    GOVT          USD            20                20000
4    2018-07   QCBO    GOVT          USD            10                10000
5    2018-08   QCBO    CORP          CAD            20                20000
```

I would like to merge or concatenate all three into one such that the result is as follows:

[image]

Key points here:

```
Total_RFQ = Done_RFQ + Not_Done_RFQ 
Total_RFQ_per_Client is the column from df1` `i.e. it reflects the totals RFQ's with product and currency removed

Total_RFQ_Volume = Done_RFQ_Volume + Not_Done_RFQ_Volume
Total_RFQ_Volume_per_Client is the column from df1` `i.e. it reflects the totals RFQ's volume product and currency removed

Note for 2018-01, client RBMI there is a Product/Currency of GOVT/USD and CORP/GBP so the `Total_RFQ_per_Client` will display 3 for each row as this is the sum for 2018-01/RBMI in df1. Same principle applies for `Total_RFQ_Volume_per_Client` 

Likewise the same situation exists for 2018-08/QCBO i.e. GOVT/USD and 
CORP/CAD.
```

My code solution is as follows but I am having issues with the merge statement joining correctly:

```
print("Join Done Trades with not Done trades",  end='\n') 
dfTemp = pd.merge(df2, df3,  how='outer', left_on=['Year_Month','Client'], right_on = ['Year_Month','Client'])
dfTemp = dfTemp.sort_values(['Client','Year_Month'], ascending=[False, True])
dfTemp = dfTemp.fillna(0)
display(dfTemp)

print("Join Done Trades/Not Done trades with Client Totals",  end='\n') 
df_Client_Product_Ccy_Hit_Rate_Volumes = pd.merge(dfTemp, df1,  how='inner', left_on=['Year_Month','Client'], right_on = ['Year_Month','Client'])
# Concatenation results in NaN hence replace missing values by 0 - sum of columns was retuning zero as 500 + Nan is Nan
df_Client_Product_Ccy_Hit_Rate_Volumes = df_Client_Product_Ccy_Hit_Rate_Volumes.fillna(0)


print("Create additional calculated columns",  end='\n') 
df_Client_Product_Ccy_Hit_Rate_Volumes['Total_RFQ'] = df_Client_Product_Ccy_Hit_Rate_Volumes['Done_RFQ'] + df_Client_Product_Ccy_Hit_Rate_Volumes['Not_Done_RFQ'] 
df_Client_Product_Ccy_Hit_Rate_Volumes['Total_RFQ_Volume'] = (df_Client_Product_Ccy_Hit_Rate_Volumes['Done_RFQ_Volume']) + df_Client_Product_Ccy_Hit_Rate_Volumes['Not_Done_RFQ_Volume']

df_Client_Product_Ccy_Hit_Rate_Volumes = df_Client_Product_Ccy_Hit_Rate_Volumes.fillna(0)
# display(df_Client_Product_Ccy_Hit_Rate_Volumes)

# Select and Order the columns of interest
df_Client_Product_Ccy_Hit_Rate_Volumes = df_Client_Product_Ccy_Hit_Rate_Volumes[['Year_Month',
                                                                                 'Client',
                                                                                 'Product_x',
                                                                                 'currency_str_x', 

                                                                                 'Done_RFQ',
                                                                                 'Not_Done_RFQ',
                                                                                 'Total_RFQ',
                                                                                 'Total_RFQ_per_Client',

                                                                                 'Done_RFQ_Volume',
                                                                                 'Not_Done_RFQ_Volume',
                                                                                 'Total_RFQ_Volume',
                                                                                 'Total_RFQ_Volume_per_Client'
                                                                ]]
# Sort 
dfTemp = df_Client_Product_Ccy_Hit_Rate_Volumes.sort_values(['Client', 'Year_Month'], ascending=[False, True]) 
display(dfTemp)
print("",  end='\n')
```

It's producing incorrect sums and is also missing the `2018-08/QCBO/CORP/CAD` row.

Any guidance on the merge would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following merge appears to work:

```
    dfTemp = pd.merge(df2, df3,  how='outer', on=['Year_Month','Client','Product','currency_str'])
    dfTemp = dfTemp.fillna(0)
    dfTemp['Total_RFQ'] = dfTemp['Done_RFQ'] + dfTemp['Not_Done_RFQ'] 
    dfTemp['Total_RFQ_Volume'] = (dfTemp['Done_RFQ_Volume']) + dfTemp['Not_Done_RFQ_Volume']
    df_Client_Product_Ccy_Hit_Rate_Volumes = pd.merge(dfTemp, df1,  how='inner', left_on=['Year_Month','Client'], right_on = ['Year_Month','Client'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think "join" statement would make a better work here:

```
import pandas as pd 

df_joined = df1.set_index('Year_Month ').join(df2.set_index('Year_Month '))

df_joined = df_joined.set_index('Year_Month ').join(df3.set_index('Year_Month '))
```

If you want the index again as an incremental number:

```
df_joined = df_joined.reset_index()
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey Francisco, I'm getting "columns overlap but no suffix error" on that. There's also the df3 which needs merging.

Comment: I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645515/pandas-join-issue-columns-overlap-but-no-suffix-specified) will solve you the suffix problem