# ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['Week_0'], dtype='object')

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
data = data.join(pd.DataFrame(predicted_order,index=data.index).add_prefix('Week_'))

print(data)

data.to_csv('smallys_ARMA.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

After first time execution, a Week_0 new column added to the dataframe. After second time execution, I am getting following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-adcd0043cad7> in <module>()
      2 
      3 #data['Week_{}'.format(i)] = predicted_order
----> 4 data = data.join(pd.DataFrame(predicted_order,index=data.index).add_prefix('Week_'))
      5 
      6 #data = data.iloc[:, len(data)].add_prefix('Week_')

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in join(self, other, on, how, lsuffix, rsuffix, sort)
   5314         # For SparseDataFrame's benefit
   5315         return self._join_compat(other, on=on, how=how, lsuffix=lsuffix,
-> 5316                                  rsuffix=rsuffix, sort=sort)
   5317 
   5318     def _join_compat(self, other, on=None, how='left', lsuffix='', rsuffix='',

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _join_compat(self, other, on, how, lsuffix, rsuffix, sort)
   5329             return merge(self, other, left_on=on, how=how,
   5330                          left_index=on is None, right_index=True,
-> 5331                          suffixes=(lsuffix, rsuffix), sort=sort)
   5332         else:
   5333             if on is not None:

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     56                          copy=copy, indicator=indicator,
     57                          validate=validate)
---> 58     return op.get_result()
     59 
     60 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in get_result(self)
    586 
    587         llabels, rlabels = items_overlap_with_suffix(ldata.items, lsuf,
--> 588                                                      rdata.items, rsuf)
    589 
    590         lindexers = {1: left_indexer} if left_indexer is not None else {}

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in items_overlap_with_suffix(left, lsuffix, right, rsuffix)
   5024         if not lsuffix and not rsuffix:
   5025             raise ValueError('columns overlap but no suffix specified: %s' %
-> 5026                              to_rename)
   5027 
   5028         def lrenamer(x):

ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['Week_0'], dtype='object')
```

What I want is generating dynamic column names of this format : `Week_i`  where `i is a positive integer`. After each time of execution I want to add a new column to the dataframe. The code will be run for an unknown number of times, and it may be executed once today. then the next execution may be after 2 days. Each time the newly generated column should get a name dynamically generated.

Comment: You have columns with same name in both your data frame `data` and your newly constructed dataframe with columns starting with `Week_`. Then there's ambiguity and the error is raised. Use the `lsuffix` or `rsuffix` args of your `data.join` function

Comment: see related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645515/pandas-join-issue-columns-overlap-but-no-suffix-specified