# Join on column in pandas

Tags: pandas, join

So this works as expected:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':[123,456],'price1':[23,34]}).set_index('date')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':[456,789],'price2':[22,32]}).set_index('date')
df1.join(df2, how='outer')

      price1  price2
date                
123     23.0     NaN
456     34.0    22.0
789      NaN    32.0
```

But if I don't set the index, it causes an error:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':[123,456],'price1':[23,34]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':[456,789],'price2':[22,32]})
df1.join(df2, on='date', how='outer')

ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['date'], dtype='object')
```

Why is this, and am I incorrect for supposing they should give the same result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas join issue: columns overlap but no suffix specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645515/pandas-join-issue-columns-overlap-but-no-suffix-specified)

Comment: What I don't understand is what's the point of "joining" on a column if you then output separate columns in the result? It doesn't seem to work as I'd expect (or as it would in SQL). Whether the column you're joining on is the index or not doesn't seem relevant to me, but maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: you are attempting to join the `date` column of  `df2` on the index of `df1`. `.join` is for joining on indices, `.merge` provides more options for joining on different combinations of columns or indices.

Comment: Ah that's good to know. Is it possible to join on the `date` column of both, without changing their indexes?

Comment: Yes, use `.merge` instead of `.join`. `pd.merge(df1, df2, on='date')`.

Comment: Also see [SO: Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645882/7758804)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just to add the two dataframes and not joining by a certain column, you need to add suffixes so not to create columns with the same name. e.g.:

```
df1.join(df2, how='outer', lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right')
```

if you want to join on the column you should use merge:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='outer')
```

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I do actually want to join on that column, not output two new columns.

Comment: I kept using join, concat and a very slow for loop. Merge is better +1