# Merge 4 or more Dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I've read the following thread: [How to merge multiple dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327999/how-to-merge-multiple-dataframes)

```
data_frames = [df1, df2, df3]
df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['DATE'],
                                            how='outer'), data_frames)
```

But it only works for up to 3 dataframes. When I want to merge 4 or more, it doesn't work. How can I merge 4 or more dataframes in Python?

The problem seems to be that I have a column named "Closed" in all dataframes.

Here is the error I get

```
/var/folders/51/_yntlxy96y7_vwm7t537w8700000gn/T/ipykernel_1021/437066834.py:18: FutureWarning: Passing 'suffixes' which cause duplicate columns {'High_x', 'Close_x', 'Open_x', 'Volume_x', 'Adj Close_x', 'Low_x'} in the result is deprecated and will raise a MergeError in a future version. df_merged = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['Date'], how='outer'), data_frames)
```

Here is the head of 4 dataframes used as input:

```
print(portfolio_all[0].head) 
print(portfolio_all[1].head) 
print(portfolio_all[2].head) 
print(portfolio_all[3].head)
<bound method NDFrame.head of            Date       Open       High  ...      Close  Adj Close    Volume
0    2020-07-02  50.060001  70.800003  ...  69.410004  69.410004  18371900
1    2020-07-06  73.393997  96.510002  ...  81.190002  81.190002  13467900
2    2020-07-07  83.800003  89.379997  ...  78.790001  78.790001   4602800
3    2020-07-08  79.000000  79.389999  ...  68.510002  68.510002   3499200
4    2020-07-09  73.970001  79.910004  ...  77.010002  77.010002   4178700
..          ...        ...        ...  ...        ...        ...       ...
812  2023-09-25  11.820000  11.920000  ...  11.690000  11.690000   1568300
813  2023-09-26  11.550000  11.765000  ...  11.380000  11.380000   1489800
814  2023-09-27  11.500000  11.620000  ...  11.530000  11.530000   1635300
815  2023-09-28  11.590000  11.830000  ...  11.690000  11.690000   1452800
816  2023-09-29  11.890000  12.080000  ...  11.620000  11.620000   1563800

[817 rows x 7 columns]>
<bound method NDFrame.head of            Date       Open       High  ...      Close  Adj Close    Volume
0    2020-08-27  23.100000  25.000000  ...  21.219999  21.219999  82219700
1    2020-08-28  23.980000  24.400000  ...  22.790001  22.790001  44847300
2    2020-08-31  22.690001  22.790001  ...  20.500000  20.500000  20816000
3    2020-09-01  20.980000  21.790001  ...  21.610001  21.610001  15291400
4    2020-09-02  21.990000  22.000000  ...  21.090000  21.090000   9090100
..          ...        ...        ...  ...        ...        ...       ...
773  2023-09-25  16.530001  16.790001  ...  16.690001  16.690001  16998300
774  2023-09-26  16.320000  16.809999  ...  16.219999  16.219999   6960300
775  2023-09-27  16.360001  16.690001  ...  16.690001  16.690001   8127900
776  2023-09-28  16.490000  17.420000  ...  17.219999  17.219999  11415300
777  2023-09-29  18.020000  18.459999  ...  18.360001  18.360001  11957500

[778 rows x 7 columns]>
<bound method NDFrame.head of             Date        Open        High  ...       Close   Adj Close     Volume
0     2005-08-05    6.600000   15.121000  ...   12.254000   12.254000  226811000
1     2005-08-08   13.775000   15.398000  ...   11.550000   11.550000  154889000
2     2005-08-09   12.050000   12.530000  ...    9.610000    9.610000   86677000
3     2005-08-10   10.100000   10.350000  ...    9.175000    9.175000   49638000
4     2005-08-11    9.120000   10.050000  ...    9.790000    9.790000   73248000
         ...         ...         ...  ...         ...         ...        ...
4564  2023-09-25  130.009995  132.350006  ...  132.050003  132.050003     849500
4565  2023-09-26  132.059998  132.600006  ...  131.009995  131.009995    1062400
4566  2023-09-27  131.130005  131.740005  ...  131.529999  131.529999    1222000
4567  2023-09-28  131.389999  132.850006  ...  132.449997  132.449997    1074000
4568  2023-09-29  135.860001  136.529999  ...  134.350006  134.350006    1741400

[4569 rows x 7 columns]>
<bound method NDFrame.head of             Date       Open       High  ...      Close  Adj Close    Volume
0     2015-04-16  31.000000  35.740002  ...  30.000000  30.000000  19763300
1     2015-04-17  29.770000  30.299999  ...  27.580000  27.580000   3965500
2     2015-04-20  28.770000  28.900000  ...  24.900000  24.900000   3076200
3     2015-04-21  24.969999  26.040001  ...  25.750000  25.750000   2184700
4     2015-04-22  26.000000  26.240000  ...  25.120001  25.120001   1442500
         ...        ...        ...  ...        ...        ...       ...
2125  2023-09-25  63.099998  65.250000  ...  64.720001  64.720001   2738300
2126  2023-09-26  64.290001  64.519997  ...  61.869999  61.869999   3961200
2127  2023-09-27  61.770000  63.160000  ...  61.889999  61.889999   3171400
2128  2023-09-28  61.299999  63.959999  ...  63.750000  63.750000   3666800
2129  2023-09-29  64.790001  65.870003  ...  64.580002  64.580002   3269900

[2130 rows x 7 columns]>
```

Comment: Can you tell, what is not working   or what your output that you are getting.  I was able to merge 6 data frames with the same code as above.

Comment: Added a new solution -  Can you tell us what is the expected output

Answer (score 1):

**If the dataframe has same column name** -

**Solution 1 -** You should add the suffix to stop them from overlapping the columns

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02'], 'Close': [100, 101]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02'], 'Close': [105, 106]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02'], 'Close': [110, 111]})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02'], 'Close': [115, 116]})
df5 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02'], 'Close': [120, 121]})
df6 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02'], 'Close': [125, 126]})


data_frames = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6]

df_merged = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['Date'], how='outer', suffixes=('', '_right')), data_frames)

print(df_merged)
```

`the output should have column names with suffix`

```
         Date  Close  Close_right  Close_right  Close_right  Close_right  Close_right
0  2023-01-01    100          105          110          115          120          125
1  2023-01-02    101          106          111          116          121          126
```

**Solution 2 with New Sample Data**

I see no reason to use `merge` and you can use `pandas concat` option to combine the dataframes

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
    'Date': ['2020-07-02', '2020-07-06', '2020-07-07', '2020-07-08', '2020-07-09'],
    'Open': [50.06, 73.39, 83.80, 79.00, 73.97],
    'High': [70.80, 96.51, 89.38, 79.39, 79.91],
    'Low': [50.06, 73.39, 83.80, 79.00, 73.97],
    'Close': [69.41, 81.19, 78.79, 68.51, 77.01],
    'Adj Close': [69.41, 81.19, 78.79, 68.51, 77.01],
    'Volume': [18371900, 13467900, 4602800, 3499200, 4178700]
}

data2 = {
    'Date': ['2020-08-27', '2020-08-28', '2020-08-31', '2020-09-01', '2020-09-02'],
    'Open': [23.10, 23.98, 22.69, 20.98, 21.99],
    'High': [25.00, 24.40, 22.79, 21.79, 22.00],
    'Low': [23.10, 23.98, 22.69, 20.98, 21.99],
    'Close': [21.22, 22.79, 20.50, 21.61, 21.09],
    'Adj Close': [21.22, 22.79, 20.50, 21.61, 21.09],
    'Volume': [82219700, 44847300, 20816000, 15291400, 9090100]
}


data3 = {
    'Date': ['2005-08-05', '2005-08-08', '2005-08-09', '2005-08-10', '2005-08-11'],
    'Open': [6.60, 13.77, 12.05, 10.10, 9.12],
    'High': [15.12, 15.39, 12.53, 10.35, 10.05],
    'Low': [6.60, 13.77, 12.05, 10.10, 9.12],
    'Close': [12.25, 11.55, 9.61, 9.17, 9.79],
    'Adj Close': [12.25, 11.55, 9.61, 9.17, 9.79],
    'Volume': [226811000, 154889000, 86677000, 49638000, 73248000]
}

data4 = {
    'Date': ['2015-04-16', '2015-04-17', '2015-04-20', '2015-04-21', '2015-04-22'],
    'Open': [31.00, 29.77, 28.77, 24.97, 26.00],
    'High': [35.74, 30.30, 28.90, 26.04, 26.24],
    'Low': [31.00, 29.77, 28.77, 24.97, 26.00],
    'Close': [30.00, 27.58, 24.90, 25.75, 25.12],
    'Adj Close': [30.00, 27.58, 24.90, 25.75, 25.12],
    'Volume': [19763300, 3965500, 3076200, 2184700, 1442500]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data4)

data_frames = [df1, df2, df3,df4]

combined_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4], ignore_index=True)

print(combined_df)
```

**Output**

```
          Date   Open   High    Low  Close  Adj Close     Volume
0   2020-07-02  50.06  70.80  50.06  69.41      69.41   18371900
1   2020-07-06  73.39  96.51  73.39  81.19      81.19   13467900
2   2020-07-07  83.80  89.38  83.80  78.79      78.79    4602800
3   2020-07-08  79.00  79.39  79.00  68.51      68.51    3499200
4   2020-07-09  73.97  79.91  73.97  77.01      77.01    4178700
5   2020-08-27  23.10  25.00  23.10  21.22      21.22   82219700
6   2020-08-28  23.98  24.40  23.98  22.79      22.79   44847300
7   2020-08-31  22.69  22.79  22.69  20.50      20.50   20816000
8   2020-09-01  20.98  21.79  20.98  21.61      21.61   15291400
9   2020-09-02  21.99  22.00  21.99  21.09      21.09    9090100
10  2005-08-05   6.60  15.12   6.60  12.25      12.25  226811000
11  2005-08-08  13.77  15.39  13.77  11.55      11.55  154889000
12  2005-08-09  12.05  12.53  12.05   9.61       9.61   86677000
13  2005-08-10  10.10  10.35  10.10   9.17       9.17   49638000
14  2005-08-11   9.12  10.05   9.12   9.79       9.79   73248000
15  2015-04-16  31.00  35.74  31.00  30.00      30.00   19763300
16  2015-04-17  29.77  30.30  29.77  27.58      27.58    3965500
17  2015-04-20  28.77  28.90  28.77  24.90      24.90    3076200
18  2015-04-21  24.97  26.04  24.97  25.75      25.75    2184700
19  2015-04-22  26.00  26.24  26.00  25.12      25.12    1442500
```

[image]

Comment: In my Dataframes I have a common column called Date, but I have columns named "Close" which take the same name when merged. Can you give me a working example where the dataframes have a common column named "Close"?

Comment: So, instead of having value1, value2, and so on, you have only Close  as columng name right?

Comment: Yes that is true

Comment: if you  have the same column names like date and close and you are trying to merge them, you can add suffixes to the merge function or there will be high chance of having columns overlapped [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645515/pandas-join-issue-columns-overlap-but-no-suffix-specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645515/pandas-join-issue-columns-overlap-but-no-suffix-specified) - reference

Comment: @adrCoder - Just added the another small script to my answer. If thats not what you're expecting, can you give the sampel input and the expected outptu for you question that way, we can help you nore faster and directly to the question

Comment: I edited my original post and added input there